# Creating keys for a generic React container

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm working on a React component that accepts a list of data items, a function that constructs a component from the data items, and formats the items into a table.  The code looks something like this:

```
export default class DataGrid extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.generateChild = item => this.props.template(item);
    }
    render () {
        return tabulate (
                  this.props.data.map(this.generateChild),
                  this.props.cols
              );
    }
}

export function tabulate (components, cols)
{
    return <table><tbody>{
              collateRows (components, cols).map(cols => 
                 <tr>{cols.map(v => 
                     <td key={keyOf(v)}>{v}</td>)
                 }</tr>)
           }</tbody></table>;
}
```

(where `collateRows` is a function that allocates the data values into a 2D array of rows and columns)

What I'm wondering is, how can I write the `keyOf` function referred to there: it needs to produce an identifier that is unique to each item, but remains consistent across calls for the same item.  It also needs to do this with as little knowledge about the data item itself as possible, as this is intended to be a completely generic component that can be used for any reasonable data type.

What I do know is that the `template` property is a function that returns a React component, and that *that* component has a property `key` that contains an appropriate value.  But I don't seem to be able to access that property (I get `undefined` and a warning that says I should provide another prop with the same value, but as I want to be able to use this with any component type, I don't see how this would work...), so what can I do instead?

Comment: I personally haven't used this, but, perhaps the 'react-key-index' package might be worth considering (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index) if it's not otherwise possible to provide a unique ID of your own with each element in your data array for generating component keys.

Comment: @FinbarrO'B - That's a possibility. It's just annoying that there doesn't seem to be any way of getting the keys that *already exist* in the components.